# Read an expression

Tags: c++, regex, boost

Can someone explain to me how can I do to read some information from a file using regex?

The information that I want to read is in this format:

```
INT    "integer"
FLOAT  "real"
```

To be more precise, I hardly know how to do this using boost, so I need help.

Comment: How much programming do you know? Have you made any attempt yet?

Comment: Do you know how to use Regexes, just not in Boost (or C++11)?  Or do you not know regexes either?

Comment: What language are you using? c++? Or any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though the language you wish to parse using regular expressions contains a finite number of keywords follows by identifiers consisting of a subset of symbols from your alphabet surrounded by quotation marks. Here is how to think about forming such a regular expression.

Let *Σ* be the set of terminal characters in your language. For each identifier, you must form a regular expression that looks like

- *R*<sub>κ</sub> = κ · ' ' · " · (α ∪ β ∪ ... ∪ ψ ∪ ω)<sup>*</sup> · "

where *κ* is the desired keyword formed by concatenation of terminal symbols and *α*, *β*,..., *ψ*, *ω* ∈ *Σ* are the permissible identifier terminals. For instance, let *Σ* = {I,N,T,F,L,O,A,i,n,t,e,g,r,a,l,",,' '}. Then

- *R*<sub>INT</sub> = I · N · T · ' ' · " · (i ∪ n ∪ t ∪ e ∪ g ∪ r ∪ a ∪ l)<sup>*</sup> · "
- *R*<sub>REAL</sub> = R · E · A · L · ' ' · " · (i ∪ n ∪ t ∪ e ∪ g ∪ r ∪ a ∪ l)<sup>*</sup> · "

To form a regular expression that matches any sequence of the *R*<sub>κ</sub>, merely form the Kleene closure of the union of the *R*<sub>κ</sub> with whatever additions are necessary for the syntax you're working with, or the Kleene closure of the concatenation of the union of the subexpressions matching identifiers and the Kleene closure of the union of the permissible identifiers.

Comment: Wait.  What? Well this deserves a +1 if for no other reason that using so many bits.